# pdfviewer retain old pdf value

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

How can i load pdf to pdfViewer in devexpress. i have the following code to load pdf from `xtraGrid` to `EditForm` but pdfViewer load the first record pdf file and Retain it. How can i reset pdf, when EditForm is close?

//wHLDRWGTextEdit- in the code below contains the file path

```
   private void ucFabLog_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)//ucFabLog is custom EditForm
        {

            try
            {
                FileStream stream = new FileStream(wHLDRWGTextEdit.Text, FileMode.Open);
                pdfViewer1.LoadDocument(stream);
           }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {

            }

        }
```

I tried the following by adding `pdfViewer1.Refresh();` and `pdfViewer1.DetachStreamAfterLoadComplete = false;` but still show PDF from another record

```
      private void ucFabLog_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) //ucFabLog is custom EditForm
    {

        try
        {
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(wHLDRWGTextEdit.Text, FileMode.Open);
            pdfViewer1.DetachStreamAfterLoadComplete = false;
            pdfViewer1.LoadDocument(stream);
            pdfViewer1.Refresh();
                        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {

        }

    }
```

Comment: I have no experience with DevExpress, but I am guessing it's due to the `stream` is still open? I don't see you `Closing` or `Disposing` your stream. Wrap your stream in `using`. Also did a quick google, this piece of code `PdfViewerControl1.DocumentSource = null;` may help.

Comment: @12seconds when i add `pdfViewer1.Dispose();` next to `       pdfViewer1.LoadDocument(stream);`now it doesnt load any pdf, where can i place it?

Comment: `Closing()` and `Dispose()` should be the last thing you do after you finish with your `stream`. Regardless did you try `.DocumentSource = null;` ?

Comment: @12seconds its weird the same code works on button click but not on `Form_load` events after the first one keeps shown me the first pdf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If **ucFabLog** is your custom Edit Form, I should note that this control is created only once when you invoke the Edit Form at the first time. Thus, the **Load** event will be raised only once. Try the **VisibleChanged** event instead.

Comment: Thank you @Svetlana you mean like this ` private void ucFabLog_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                this.pdfViewer1.LoadDocument(wHLDRWGTextEdit.Text);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }` and nothing in `Load Event`?

Comment: you are the BEST!!!!!. you have no idea how many hours i spend. Thank you Thank you!!!